# Возможно ли написать ротатор баннеров на swift в storyboard?

Tags: swift

В swift новичок. Можно ли написать ротатор рекламных баннеров в storyboard, чтобы картинки (используется button с картинкой в background) менялись при каждой загрузке страницы приложения и каждая из них была бы связана с определенным адресом в интернете. И при нажатии на кнопку открывалась страница в интернете.
Переход по ссылке реализовал, но только с одной картинкой.
Вот код:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func bunnerMainController(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let defaultURL = NSURL(string: "https://link.ru/")!
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(defaultURL)")!)
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что нужно использовать массив или словарь, но как реализовать не знаю. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Чуть поменял код. Теперь при каждой загрузке страницы отображается случайная картинка в background кнопки. Теперь надо как-то связать картинку с адресом в интернете, чтобы пользователь по клику переходил на нужную страницу. Помогите разобраться.
Вот новый код:

```
import UIKit

class ScalaApgarTextViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let images = [UIImage(named: "allradru"), UIImage(named: "aliexpress")]
        let imag = images.randomElement()
        
        
        bunnerImageBackground.setImage((imag as! UIImage), for: .normal)
        
        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bunnerImageBackground: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBAction func bunner(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let defaultURL = NSURL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/lcz5l7shqa31225e5a77253f07e8f6/")!
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(defaultURL)")!)
    }
    
    
}
```

Попробовал сделать вот так, но почему-то при клике по кнопке ничего не происходит.

```
import UIKit

class ScalaApgarTextViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let images = [UIImage(named: "allradru"), UIImage(named: "aliexpress")]
        let imag = images.randomElement()
        
        
        bunnerImageBackground.setImage((imag as! UIImage), for: .normal)
        
        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bunnerImageBackground: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBAction func bunner(_ sender: Any) {
        
       if bunnerImageBackground.currentBackgroundImage == UIImage(named: "allradru") {
        
        let defaultURL = NSURL(string: "https://aflink.ru/g/elgf718etq31225e5a770e020ad620/?erid=LatgBUcjU")!
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(defaultURL)")!)
        
       } else if bunnerImageBackground.currentBackgroundImage == UIImage(named: "aliexpress") {
            
           let defaultURL = NSURL(string: "https://alitems.co/g/1e8d11449431225e5a7716525dc3e8/")!
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(defaultURL)")!)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Не пойму где ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Во код. Может кому пригодиться.

```
import UIKit

class ScalaApgarTextViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let images = [UIImage(named: "allradru"), UIImage(named: "aliexpress"), UIImage(named: "cvetDivanov")]
        let imag = images.randomElement()
        
        
        bunnerImageBackground.setImage((imag as! UIImage), for: .normal)
        
        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bunnerImageBackground: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBAction func bunner(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let images = [UIImage(named: "allradru"), UIImage(named: "aliexpress"), UIImage(named: "cvetDivanov")]
       
      if bunnerImageBackground.currentImage == images[0] {
        
           UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.1.ru")!)
        
     } else if bunnerImageBackground.currentImage == images[1] {
            
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.2.ru")!)
            
      } else {
           UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.3.ru")!)
           
      }
        
    }
    
    
}
```